# Connect Persistent Volume Kubernetes to SFTP

Tags: kubernetes, ftp, sftp

I am doing the end of course work and I would like to know if I can make a regular volume a shared directory with ftp, that is to say that when you mount the disk kubeneretes takes the directory of the external ftp server.

I know it can be done with NFS but I would like to do it with SFTP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good luck ! https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/8k4c8u/how_to_offer_sftp_access_to_a_container_in/

Comment: Could also use a [fuse sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) mount as a host volume as I doubt people have spent much time trying to do this natively with kubernetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is code floating around for a FlexVolume plugin which delegates the actual mount to FUSE: https://github.com/adelton/kubernetes-flexvolume-fuse

But I have no idea if that will even compile anymore, and FlexVolume is on its way out in favor of CSI. You could write a CSI plugin on top of the FUSE FS but I don't know of any such thing already existing.

More commonly what you would do is use a RWX shared volume (such as NFS) and mount it to both the SFTP server and whatever your hosting app pod is.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using this CSI SSHFS driver for a bit with Kubernetes 1.15.10 on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and it works, though sometimes volumes get stuck unmounting when a pod is terminated (though that may be due to unrelated issues elsewhere in our cluster related to IOPS throttling):

https://github.com/chr-fritz/csi-sshfs

That project is not actively maintained, but it looks like someone may have taken up the torch to update and maintain it:

https://github.com/geoffh1977/csi-sshfs